# How to run Java code using Java code?

Tags: java

Basically, I want to do two things:

1. I want to know if there is any way that I can run Java code using Java code.
2. If it is possible, how would I show the output on my screen? (be it regular output or error or exception)

I know this is possible because one of my seniors had done it, but I don't know how he did it. Maybe he used one of Java's built-in classes.

Note: user will write the code in some text file and then I will store that file content in some variable and then maybe run that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

**Step 1: Compile the Code**
Use [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) or [Runtime](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) to construct a [Process](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) in which the Java compiler compiles their code. (Note that this requires that a Java compiler be available on the system at runtime).

**Step 2: Invoke their Code**
There are two ways to invoke their code. You can again use a ProcessBuilder or Runtime object to construct a process in which you execute their Java code. You can use the Process's [getInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()) and [getOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()) functions to read from and write to the other process. An alternative is that you can use [Class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and the various reflection APIs to load their code and execute it directly within Java.

Comment: The Java compiler is frequently found in the JDK or brought along as the standalone Eclipse compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to some how invoke a compiler (such as Suns javac), parse its output in case of errors and load the resulting classes dynamically.

There is no API-classes in the Java runtime library that will parse, compile and run Java source code.

Comment: senior who has done that, has done using some java's core inbuilt classes.
may be he had done as you say but i want to know how?

Comment: Either he built his own java parser / compiler or he used an of-the-shelf compiler backend such as suns javac, or eclipse jdt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) (so, no compiling required) for Java, take a look at [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/).
I like this one very much!

Comment: BeanShell is not under active development for several years now, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scripting language running on top of the JVM. [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) is a very good idea and it has very similar syntax compared to Java.