# How to run C# code using C# code?

Tags: c#

i had asked earlier about the same kind of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896566/how-to-run-java-code-using-java-code) but that was in java....
now for the knowledge, i want to know...

is it possible to run the one C# code using another C# code?

bcz i know C# is very powerful, so their might be some way to do this.

Comment: There is CodeDom namespace for this. Check [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2007/07/11/c-3-0-and-codedom.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same sort of deal:

- Compile the code, e.g. using `CSharpCodeProvider`
- Execute the code, e.g. using reflection

If you [download Snippy](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) from the C# in Depth web site, you can see a smallish example of this - basically you type in snippets of C# and it can compile and execute them for you.

Answer (score 4):

That is ultimately a runtime feature; in MS .NET, `CSharpCodeProvider` is the closest you'll get at the moment, although they have mentioned possibly looking at the "compiler as a service" in the future.

If you're happy to use Mono, [it already exists](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.CSharp) , with [REPL example](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl).

Usage (from [here](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.CSharp)):

```
  // First setup the active using statements:
  Evaluator.Run ("using System;");

  Evaluator.Run ("Console.WriteLine (\"Hello, World\");
```